# How can i add default tax to all products

Tags: tax, default

How to add default tax rate to all products in a store.

I am using magento 1.9 version

ex: I want to add 5.5% tax to all my products.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a read [here and](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-setup-taxes-step3) see if the documentations answers your question.
You can create a tax rule to be applied to a certain group of users or to all of them and then apply the created rule to all the products.